# Meaning of @ from import statement

Tags: angular, reference

I have to maintain a project built with angular 6, i have noticed original developer created bunch of helper function.
when importing it is not using relative nor absolute path, it is starting with @ like angular but it is not from angular nor located in node_module. Also it is not named starting with @.
what is the meaning of @ in this case?

import { DateUtils, ObjectUtils } from '@shared/common';

Comment: @R.Richards but it is not npm package, it is located in src/app/shared

Answer (score 0):

That is a barrel module.

The Angular documentation describes a barrel as:

A way to roll up exports from several ES2015 modules into a single convenient ES2015
module. The barrel itself is an ES2015 module file that re-exports selected exports of other ES2015 modules.